# htc explorer usb driver information

Tags: android

I want to connect my htc explorer device with my system but usb driver is not find. how can I do this issue, that my htc explorer device connect to my eclipse...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. I had the same problem and I just fixed it with Htc sync.

[Here is the Link](http://www.htc.com/help/mideast/howto_iframe.aspx?id=96745&type=1&p_id=423) for Htc Explorer.

Comment: Is this valid for windows 8 RP also? I tried to connect htc explorer, huawei sonic they aren't recognized by win8, so can't use them in Eclipse debugging...