# Determine what Context variable to use in MediaPlayer.create in Android

Tags: android, service, uri, mp3, android-context

Knotty problem with MP3 stream `MediaPlayer` in Android. I've done yet some app with it, but now I refactor the code cause of some reasons.

There is a call of a Service in the activity of Player:

```
mp3Service.playSong(getBaseContext(),url);
```

The playSong method consists of this:

```
public void playSong(Context c, String url) {
     if (this.currenturl.equals(""))
     {

         this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(url));
         this.currenturl=url;
         this.mplayer.start();
     }
     else
        {
        if (!this.currenturl.equals(url))
        {
                this.mplayer.stop();
               //this.mplayer=null; 
                 this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(url));
                 this.mplayer.start();
                 this.currenturl=url;

        } else
        {
            if (this.on==false)
            this.mplayer.start();

        };

        };
     this.on=true;
}
```

The call to `playSong` method worked normally when it was on the `ImageView` click listener! The music started to play.

But, when calling simply from player activity `onCreate` - it stops the app.
Not sure why, but it's totally hard to understand what context parameter to use here.
I've read some similar articles and documentation, but there is much fog.

How to determine what should I use for the first Context parameter here?
Does it depend on from where I call the `.playSong(Context, Uri)`? If yes, how?
Context is very abstract for new in Android, the class documentation by itself don't shed light to it.

There are many choices which I tried but I need logical reason why to use this and how to determine why app stops.

1. `getApplicationContext()`
2. `getBaseContext()`
3. `this`
4. `PlayerActivity.this`

and others. But without understanding it's not right. Maybe the error is in the other place.
But without the service call all was working.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that `Context` and when to use which kind can be a hard idea to grasp. From what I have learned, it normally seems best to use your `Activity`'s `Context` in most situations. These are my thoughts on it and somebody please correct me if I'm wrong with examples/facts.

> How to determine what should I use for the first Context parameter here? Does it depend on from where I call the .playSong(Context, Uri)? If yes, how?

Yes and not necessarily. From what I have read, you want to use the `Context` that is closest to the `Object` that needs it...use the most minimal `Context` needed.

1. If you call if from an `Activity` and the `Object` will be destroyed when that `Activity` is destroyed then use the `Activity` `Context` (here `Player.this`).
2. If you are calling a service, which has its own `Context` then use the `Service`'s `Context`.
3. If it needs access to things like System services then use `getApplicationContext()`

You said you've already read articles about using `Context` and since I don't know which ones I won't post a bunch of links. However,

[Here is a good SO answer about using getApplicationContext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

> Maybe the error is in the other place.

If you post what error you are getting then maybe we can help better to find the error

Comment: Thanks. The method of a music service is called from an Activity. So based on your answer 2) is better. I don't see where the error is because I run the app on the phone and can't debug here or in emulator. Maybe I can somehow catch the exception from this Service call?

Comment: And what's the name of the Context variable in 2)?

Comment: Just like an `Activity`...`ServiceName.this`. I don't understand why you can't debug on your phone

Comment: HTC (I've HTC Explorer) has no driver for this officially. There are some suspicious drivers from third parties, I've not installed them yet. I have `code`private PlayerService mp3Service;`\code`, but making mp3Service.this results in red mark error in IDE (cannot be resolved to a type).

Comment: You should be able to just start the `Service` and let that handle playing the song

Comment: `mp3Service.playSong(getApplicationContext(),url);` works from the `play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {`. But it doesn't work from the Activity onCreate itself... I need song to start onCreate.

Comment: Did you try using `YourActivityName.this`? Without knowing why its crashing (what the error is) I can't say what the problem is. Make sure that `mp3Service` is initialized before calling the method

Comment: Yes, it crashes too. I check with isMyServiceRunning() method, it returns true. Now I'm trying somehow to get error message

Comment: Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544850/htc-explorer-usb-driver-information) to get the drivers

Comment: Using `e.getStackTrace()[0].toString()+" "+e.getStackTrace()[1].toString()` I get this Toast on the screen: `PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:143) android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)` HTC Sync I've seen, now downloaded.

Comment: mp3Service.playSong(PlayerActivity.this,url);

Comment: AFTER THIS: `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Activity.Thread.java:1836) android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)android.app.ActivityThread.$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)`

Comment: You need to look for `Fatal Exception` and the error it gives after that

Comment: I've installed HTC Sync, now will test on it, if will work, thanks.

Comment: I moved the call of Service to onStart() method, LogCat gives the next: `07-10 19:50:51.563: E/AndroidRuntime(8024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 19:50:51.563: E/AndroidRuntime(8024): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {myappname/myappname.PlayerActivity} did not call through to super.onStart()
`

Comment: The most strange is that play launches by clicking button in PlayerActivity, but not while starting PlayerActivity...

Comment: It seems to me, that call to the player start blocks UI thread, when calling from onCreate || onResume, then app stops. So more likely that this is not from context but UI hang. So I'm trying to launch new thread for player start call, but having this done music stops after 15-50 seconds often, not sure why.